# Are there maven plugins to generate java source code (entity) classes based on a hibernate entity XML?

Tags: java, xml, maven, code-generation

I want to automate java source code generation through a maven java source code generator.
I want to create  entity classes by looking at an one big entity xml file which will have all the entities and entity relationships in a system. as far as I searched there is no such plug-in in maven for the moment.

do I have to write my own mojo to get this done?

any ideas and directions to follow will be relay appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try this plugin : http://mojo.codehaus.org/maven-hibernate3/hibernate3-maven-plugin/hbm2java-mojo.html

The hbm2java goal should be what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

If you use Eclipse or NetBeans they both have a tool to generate entity classes directly from database tables.

You would not even need to provide the XML definitions.

Answer (score -1):

There are several plugins which do code generation, but it is always a custom task, e.g. there are plugins to generate web service classes from WSDL file, or I've used querydsl's generator for query-objects.

So, first of all, decide if you are not reinventing a wheel and there are some similar projects which do what you want. It it is not a case, take any plugin which does something similar and write your own for your situation.